# Gem :: load error while migrating from MySQL to MongoDB

Tags: mysql, ruby, mongify

I am trying to migrate the Mysql DB to MongoDB using tool **Mongify** by referring the
[documentation](http://mongify.com/getting_started.html) :

i have seen , there are few posts already present regarding such migration but they mentioned issues with rails application and some dependencies on rails. however, in my case , it is just simple migration without rails.

Environment details:

- windows enterprise 7
- Mysql community server : 5.7
- Mongo db server : 4.0
- ruby : ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [i386-mingw32]
- Mysql c Connector (32 bit)

mysql server and mongo db server are working fine as a service.

rubygems environment details as follows :

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.1 (2018-03-29 patchlevel 57) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Users/irfan.sayed/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby25/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby25/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/irfan.sayed/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: C:/ProgramData
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
     - C:/Users/irfan.sayed/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - C:\windows\system32
     - C:\windows
     - C:\windows\System32\Wbem
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Application Virtualization Client
     - C:\Program Files\PuTTY\
     - C:\apache-maven-3.5.2-bin\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin
     - "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin"
     - C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
     - C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin
     - C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
     - C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
     - C:\Ruby25\bin
     - C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin
     - C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin
```

locally installed Gems are as follows :

```
activemodel (5.2.1, 4.2.10)
activerecord (5.2.1, 4.2.10)
activerecord-mysql2-adapter (0.0.3)
activesupport (5.2.1, 4.2.10)
arel (9.0.0, 6.0.4)
awesome_print (1.8.0)
backports (3.11.3)
bigdecimal (default: 1.3.4)
bson (1.12.5)
bson_ext (1.12.5)
builder (3.2.3)
bundler (1.16.3)
byebug (10.0.2)
cmath (default: 1.0.0)
coderay (1.1.2)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
coolline (0.5.0)
csv (default: 1.0.0)
cucumber (3.1.2)
cucumber-core (3.2.0)
cucumber-expressions (6.0.1)
cucumber-tag_expressions (1.1.1)
cucumber-wire (0.0.1)
date (default: 1.0.0)
dbm (default: 1.0.0)
did_you_mean (1.2.0)
diff-lcs (1.3)
etc (default: 1.0.0)
fcntl (default: 1.0.0)
fiddle (default: 1.0.0)
fileutils (default: 1.0.2)
gdbm (default: 2.0.0)
gherkin (5.1.0)
highline (1.7.8)
i18n (0.9.5, 0.7.0)
io-console (default: 0.4.6)
ipaddr (default: 1.2.0)
jazz_fingers (5.0.0)
json (default: 2.1.0)
metaclass (0.0.4)
method_source (0.9.0)
minitest (5.11.3, 5.10.3)
mocha (1.6.0)
mongify (1.3.2)
mongo (1.12.5)
multi_json (1.13.1)
multi_test (0.1.2)
mysql (2.9.1 x86-mingw32)
mysql2 (0.5.2 x86-mingw32)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
openssl (default: 2.1.0)
pg (1.0.0 x86-mingw32)
power_assert (1.1.1)
pry (0.11.3)
pry-byebug (3.6.0)
pry-coolline (0.2.5)
psych (default: 3.0.2)
rake (12.3.1, 12.3.0, 11.3.0)
rdoc (default: 6.0.1)
rspec (2.99.0)
rspec-collection_matchers (1.1.3)
rspec-core (2.99.2)
rspec-expectations (2.99.2)
rspec-mocks (2.99.4)
scanf (default: 1.0.0)
sdbm (default: 1.0.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.13 x86-mingw32)
stringio (default: 0.0.1)
strscan (default: 1.0.0)
test-unit (3.2.7)
thread_safe (0.3.6)
tzinfo (1.2.5)
unicode_utils (1.4.0)
watchr (0.7)
webrick (default: 1.4.2)
xmlrpc (0.3.0)
yard (0.9.15)
zlib (default: 1.0.0)
```

`bundle install` and `bundle update` commands are just working fine. all the dependencies are gems are resolved properly and available in default folder of ruby.

`database.config` file used as below :

```
sql_connection do
  adapter   "mysql2"
  host      "localhost"
  username  "root"
  password  "<password>"
  database  "abc"
end

mongodb_connection do
  host      "localhost"
  database  "db"
end
```

however getting following error :

```
mongify check database.config
Traceback (most recent call last):
        10: from C:/Ruby25/bin/mongify:23:in `<main>'
         9: from C:/Ruby25/bin/mongify:23:in `load'
         8: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mongify-1.3.2/bin/mongify:17
:in `<top (required)>'
         7: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mongify-1.3.2/lib/mongify/cl
i/application.rb:28:in `execute!'
         6: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mongify-1.3.2/lib/mongify/cl
i/command/worker.rb:68:in `execute'
         5: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mongify-1.3.2/lib/mongify/cl
i/command/worker.rb:99:in `check_sql_connection'
         4: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mongify-1.3.2/lib/mongify/da
tabase/sql_connection.rb:56:in `has_connection?'
         3: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mongify-1.3.2/lib/mongify/da
tabase/sql_connection.rb:40:in `setup_connection_adapter'
         2: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
         1: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in `spec'
C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'mys
ql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your
 Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (G
em::LoadError)
```

not able to understand what is still missing. is the issue with MySQL adapter OR some version compatibility issue

EDIT : further update per suggestion from matthewd

i edited Gemfile and added following line

```
s.add_development_dependency('mysql2', '~> 0.4.10')
```

ran the `bundle update --force` , `bundle install --force` but it was still installing the 0.5.x version of mysql2 gem only 
so i manually installed mysql2 gem of version 0.4.10 using following command

```
gem install mysql2 -v 0.4.10
```

but now it is giving following error

```
        11: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10-x86-mingw32/li
b/mysql2.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
        10: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
         9: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
         8: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
         7: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59
:in `require'
         6: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59
:in `require'
         5: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10-x86-mingw32/li
b/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
         4: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
         3: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
         2: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
         1: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59
:in `require'
C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': Co
uld not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter'. Make sure that
the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'm
ysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the
Gemfile. (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is misleading: you're using a version of the `mysql2` gem that's too *new* for Active Record 4.2.10 (the latest version `mongify` supports).

The simplest solution is to explicitly use an older version of `mysql2` by including a version constraint in your Gemfile entry:

```
gem "mysql2", "< 0.5"
```

Comment: thanks @matthewd . i updated answer per your suggestion. still getting new error . please suggest

Comment: The changes you describe do not match the above. You need to add the line I showed to the file named `Gemfile`.

Comment: thanks. can you please check this pastebin: https://pastebin.com/vTey9cDa

Comment: i have modified the mongify.gemspec file and added lines for mysql2. can you please check this pastebin: https://pastebin.com/vTey9cDa

Comment: I said "add the line I showed to the file named Gemfile". You said "i have modified the mongify.gemspec file". I cannot help further.

Comment: actually , it was written in Gemfile that all metadata and dependency will be fetched from gemspec so i did that. now, i have added the line to Gemfile and ran again the command bundle update --force and bundle install --force .... the command is still running

Comment: still the error :          1: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:13
5:in `rescue in require'
C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require': C
ould not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter'. Make sure that
 the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than '
mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the
 Gemfile. (LoadError)

Comment: can you please help here .....i followed the steps but still failing with above error

Answer (score 0):

Finally it is resolved. it has the issue with ruby version and 32 bit libraries. ruby 2.3 was properly tested and works fine with mongify gem. i was using latest version of ruby and was the issue.